# Category of modules over commutative monoid in symmetric monoidal category

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $\left(\cal{C},\otimes ,I\right)$ be a symmetric monoidal category (not necessarily closed) and $A$ a commutative monoid in $\cal{C}$. In his DAG III (page 95), Lurie writes:

> In many cases, the category $\cal{M}od_A\left(\cal{C}\right)$ of $A$-modules in
> $\cal{C}$ inherits the structure of a symmetric monoidal category with respect to the relative tensor product over $A$.

Where can I find conditions, details and proofs of this (seemingly) elementary fact? (I didn't find it in the book I searched - MacLane, Barr & Wells, or in books about operads, etc.)

I also need the facts that "extension of scalars" $-\otimes A$ is the left adjoint of the forgetful functor and it commutes with the tensor product. And the case when $\otimes$ distribute over the coproduct (or the bi-product).

I think I can prove most of these facts, but I want to be sure about them, and it would also be much easier to refer to them.

Comment: This sort of stuff is shown in a lot of places that I know of for topological categories, and these things follow as degenerate cases of that, but that's probably overkill.

Comment: I don't even see how can one check associativity of $\otimes_A$ if $\otimes$ doesn't preserve colimits, which is automatic in the closed case, of course. Maybe you can do it with weaker hypothesis but, do you really have a non-closed example in mind?

Comment: I don't need the closeness so I didn't check it. in one case I'm not even sure that it is closed. however, I think that in this case the tensor still preserve the colimit. the problem that you posed is one of the conditions I want to see.

Comment: I believe that having $\otimes$ distribute over reflexive coequalizers should suffice for the first paragraph, and so having $\otimes$ distribute over finite colimits should suffice for the first and second paragraphs. But I'd need some time to track down suitable references.

Comment: As an $A$-module is an algebra for the monad $A \otimes - \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$, you could use the references in this answer: http://mathoverflow.net/a/75929/10368. The sufficient condition there is that the module category has reflexive coequalizers; I'm not sure if it is also necessary.

Comment: One reference is "Dualizations and antipodes, Applied Categorical Structures 11 (2003) 229-260". See Section 5 there. It defines Comod rather than Mod, but it is essentially the same. Here's a pdf http://maths.mq.edu.au/~street/Antipode.pdf

Comment: And the extension of scalars-forgetful adjunction can be understood as coming from the special case of the adjunction $f_\ast \dashv f^\ast$ taking $f$ to be the unique monoid map $I \rightarrow A$, where $I$ is the monoidal unit with the obvious monoid structure.

Comment: There probably are references that prove these results only for ordinary symmetric monoidal categories, but if you can't find them, you could just quote Lurie (the infinity-categorical case he handles really is a generalization of the ordinary category case). In particular, @ToddTrimble is right that $\otimes$ preserving reflexive coequalizers in each variable separately is enough for the first two paragraphs. See Theorem 4.5.2.1 of Higher Algebra for the symmetric monoidal structure and Proposition 4.4.3.12 for the identification of this monoidal product with the relative tensor product.

Comment: By the way, in Higher Algebra instead of reflexive coequalizers you'll find "geometric realizations", i.e., colimits indexed by $\Delta^{\mathrm{op}}$. But in ordinary categories these can be reduced to colimits over $\Delta_{\le 1}^{\mathrm{op}}$, that is, to reflexive coequalizers, as Todd said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One needs that $C$ is cocomplete and that $\otimes$ preserves colimits in each variable (and then $\mathrm{Mod}_C(A)$ will have the corresponding properties). More precisely, you only need that $C$ has reflexive coequalizers and that $\otimes$ preserves them in each variable. This has been known for decades, but the first clear write-up of this, at least I know of, is [Florian Marty's](http://thesesups.ups-tlse.fr/540/) thesis. You can also find a discussion on this in my [thesis](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1716), Section 4.1 (and Chapter 6 for the issue on reflexive coequalizers). See also [MO/114457](http://athoverflow.net/questions/114457) for a discussion of the internal homs by Todd Trimble.

*Edit.* Here are some other references, which even discuss the case where $- \otimes A$ is replaced by a (suitable) symmetric monoidal monad:

> H. Lindner. Commutative monads. In Deuxiéme colloque sur
>   l'algébre des catégories. Amiens-1975. Résumés des conférences,
>   pages 283-288. Cahiers de topologie et géométrie différentielle
>   catégoriques, tome 16, nr. 3, 1975.
>
> R. Guitart. Tenseurs et machines. Cahiers de Topologie et
>   Géométrie Différentielle Catégoriques, 21(1):5-62, 1980.
>
> A. Kock. Closed categories generated by commutative monads.
>   Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society, 12(04):405-424,
>   1971.
>
> G. J. Seal. Tensors, monads and actions. Theory Appl. Categ.,
>   28:No. 15, 403-433, 2013.

If I recall correctly, some of these references restrict the monads in such a way that they are of the form $- \otimes A$ anyway.

Comment: Well you do know of a slightly earlier write up: the very DAG III that the OP mentioned is from 2007 and contains the more general statement for $\infty$-categories. :)

Comment: I would never cite a $\infty$-categorical result for a basic result about categories. Because the development is vice versa ...

Comment: I wouldn't cite an $\infty$-categorical result for a fact about ordinary categories either. (The ":)" indicated my remark was tongue in cheek.) I do find it funny that the earliest reference found so far seems to be DAG III when the result must have been known much earlier.

Answer (score 2):

An early and published reference for the first question is:

- M. Hovey, B. Shipley, J. Smith: pp. 15 in: *Symmetric spectra*, J. Amer. Math. Soc. **13** (2000) 149-208 [[arXiv:math/9801077](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9801077), [doi:10.1090/S0894-0347-99-00320-3](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-99-00320-3)]

The symmetric monoidal structure on the category of internal modules is Lemma 2.2.2 (and its closure is Lemma 2.2.8).